# KeyConditionExpression Not working on my table

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, boto3, dynamodb-queries

I am trying to fetch data by filtering the date which is given by me.
For example:
I want the data which record date is greater than the given date.

Table Structure:

```json
[
  {'AttributeName': 'date', 'AttributeType': 'S'}, 
  {'AttributeName': 'listing_id', 'AttributeType': 'S'}, 
  {'AttributeName': 'order_id', 'AttributeType': 'S'}, 
  {'AttributeName': 'username', 'AttributeType': 'S'}
]
```

```py
    response = tblEth_orders.query(
        IndexName = 'date-index',
        KeyConditionExpression=Key('date').gt(str("Fri Apr 16 2021 19:14:07 GMT+0000 (Coordinated Universal Time)"))
       )
```

Output

> Error
> botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (ValidationException) when calling the Query operation: Query key condition not supported

Can anyone share how to write the query for fetching in between records by date.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the problem is that:

- You are missing the partition key in your key condition expression
- Additionally, double check that 'date' is the sort key of the index you're querying